# Holoviews - opts for plots throwing AttributeError

Tags: python-3.x, attributes, bokeh, holoviews

I am trying to overlay two plots eventually and therefore would like to customize each with different styles. However, I cannot seem to be able to use opts at all

```
import pandas as pd
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts
hv.extension('bokeh', 'matplotlib')
hv.notebook_extension('bokeh','matplotlib')

# Declaring data
filepath = 'somefilepath+somefile.csv'
df  = pd.read_csv(filepath, skipinitialspace = True, encoding = 'utf-8')
curves = hv.HoloMap({col: hv.Curve(df, 'Index', col) for col in df.columns},
               kdims='Column')

curves.opts(
    opts.Area(color='#fff8dc', line_width=2),
    opts.Curve(color='black'))
```

Gives:

```
AttributeError: type object 'opts' has no attribute 'Area'
```

And this error shows up with every opts options, not only area. I can use the cell magic option but I don't know how I would apply different styles to different plots then.

Answer (score 1):

This spelling of options (instead of notebook magics) is a feature of the very latest release, you will need to update your version of Holoviews (or use the old way).

Comment: Right -- please update to holoviews 1.11 or later (see `hv.__version__` to verify you get the right one), e.g. using `conda install -c pyviz holoviews`.